# how get imei on Android 10 with device administrator

Tags: android

I need to get the imei of the Android 10 device. The application is already admin of the device.
In official documentation ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#EXTRA_PROVISIONING_IMEI ) indicates to use DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_IMEI but no success so far

So far it can only get device id.

If someone knew how to help me, I'm very grateful

Comment: [Elsewhere in Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids) it says _"Starting in Android 10, apps must have the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE privileged permission in order to access the device's non-resettable identifiers, which include both IMEI and serial number."_ which would mean that you can't get the IMEI, but there's also _"Note: If your app is the device or profile owner app, you need only the READ_PHONE_STATE permission to access non-resettable device identifiers, even if your app targets Android 10 or higher. "_

Comment: So, if your app is a _"device owner"_ you just need the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.

Comment: I have this problem too. Did you find any solutions?
P.S. Admin and READ_PHONE_STATE permission are not work for me((

Comment: Hello @andrefarinh, can you please let me know how you got the device id?